# Defining path of the file where require is called

Tags: ruby

I am writing a gem, which should automatically define the path of the file where this gem is called.

Here is how it should work:

```
 # inside some custom.rb file   
 require 'my_super_gem'
   # after require gem should automatically define the path of custom.rb file
```

I thought that `__FILE__` inside gem module is a good idea, but it defines the path of the gem module, but not of the file with `require 'my_super_gem'`.

Are there any possible solutions?

Comment: Not sure what "automatically define the path of the file" means. Which file, custom.rb? Are you having trouble requiring a file or loading a gem? Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's the feature of the gem. When you add it to the file - it knows the file path (path of custom.rb). This information is used in further operations.

Comment: So the gem needs to know who/what required it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parse the result of

```
caller.first
```

or try to look into

```
loaded_features
```